# XSRF Security Token missing in jira-python

Tags: python, jira

I'm using jira-python to loop through all of our users and add them to a specific group.  One would think that the 'add_user_to_group' function would have done this, but I ended up having to customize it a bit.  At any rate, it mostly worked except for a dozen users that are triggering the 'XSRF Security Token Missing' error.  I can't see any common thread in those users that distinguishes them from any body else.  If I log into jira I can add the users manually.  I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Here's my (slightly modified) add_user_to_group function:

```
def add_user_to_group(username, group):
  url = jira._options['server'] + '/secure/admin/user/EditUserGroups.jspa'
  payload = {
      'groupsToJoin': group,
      'name': username,
      'join': 'submit'}
  connect = jira._session.post(url, headers=jira._options['headers'], data=payload)
  if connect.status_code == 200:
      content = connect.content.decode('utf8')
      if content.find('class="error">') != -1:
        m = re.search('class="error">(.*)</div>', content)
        if m:
          msg = m.groups()[0]
          if msg == 'A user with that username already exists.':
              print msg
              return True
          else:
              print "your message is: ", msg
              return False
      elif 'XSRF Security Token Missing' in content:
          print('XSRF Security Token Missing')
          return False
      else:
          return True
  return False
```

Comment: How many users are you adding? You could retry with a sleep between each call to add_user_to_group. You could also display the exact context value since it's just guessing that the problem is XSRF

Comment: We have thousands of users, but only these 12 or so seem to a consistent problem.  I looked at the context value, and it did indeed have the XSRF error message.

Comment: Sleep call did not help.